# How to define a const array whose data is unknown at compile time

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to store vertices data of a mesh in a class.
Each instance has an array of floats and is accessible via a getter that returns the array pointer.
The data of the array should be const, as well as the array itself.
So my first thought was to declare the member this way:

```
const float * const m_vertices;  // const pointer to const floats
```

the problem is that the actual data is not know at compile time (loaded from a file, procedurally generated...)

Is there a way to ensure the data will be left untouched **except** when it's initialized (in the constructor for instance)?

EDIT : 
I tried what joseph proposed :

```cpp
//Mesh class
Mesh::Mesh(const float *vertices)
: m_vertices(vertices)
{
}

//creation of data
int size = 10; //this can't be const because the number of vertices is not known at compile time 
float arr[size]; //error : "size" is not const
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    arr[i] = i;
}
Mesh m = Mesh(arr); //this apparently works... But the constructor is expecting a const float *. Here i'm giving a float *. Why does this works ?
```

Comment: Make your "getter" a `const` member of a class, and the actual pointer or array a private member that can be initialised at run time (e.g. in the constructor of the class).   Ensure you don't provide any other non-`const` function that provides access to the data.   Also, you'll probably need t means of storing the number of elements, and accessing that number.

Comment: That was the alternative I thought of.
But nothing prevents the data to be modified as the getter will return a float * and not a const float *

Comment: Then return a `const float *`.    That prevents changing the data.

Comment: EDIT : Ok nevermind, you can return a const float * even though the underlying data is not const ? I have a lot of trouble understanding how the const keyword works tbh

Comment: A `const float *` effectively tells the compiler that the pointed-to `float` (or `float`s) should not be modified.    A `float *` tells the compiler that modifying the `float` data is permitted.   Now, taking a `float *` and adding a proviso of "shall not modify" does no harm - so there is no need to prevent it.   Going the other way (removing `const`) permits modification of something that should not be modified (i.e. stops the compiler diagnosing the attempt as an error).

Comment: Ok, so const is effectively just for the compiler, it does not change how the underlying data is handled in memory ? Is there a way to actually forbid some part of memory (e.g causing a segfault if tried to be modified) instead of just "marking it as read only" ?

Comment: @user29223 no way I know of that's built into C++. You may be allowed to set up some access walls using target-specific API functions or direct hardware access.

Comment: regarding your problem with `float arr[size];`: in Standard C++ the array dimensions MUST be constant and known at compile time (note: some of the major compilers allow variable dimensions by extension). If the array is always 10 elements, you could `const int size = 10;`. If not you should probably use a `std::vector` and use the `data` method to get the internal array. `std::vector<float> vec(size); Mesh m = Mesh(vec.data());` Note: whatever you use, make absolutely certain that its scope exceeds the lifetime of `m`.

Comment: On the return type of a function, a `const` pointer prevents the caller using that pointer to change the pointed-to data.  The compiler enforces that, but it doesn't prevent that data being changed by other means (e.g. via another pointer that is not `const`).   If (say) global data is specified `const`, then the compiler MAY place that data into some read-only area of memory - since any access to that data without `const` (e.g. using a non-`const` pointer) either is diagnosed as an error, or has introduced some form of undefined behaviour (in which case, all bets are off).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exact type you want. The constructor is allowed to write data to a `const` field:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    const float *const m_vertices;
    Foo(const float *vertices) : m_vertices(vertices) {}
};
```

Although there's no guarantee here that the caller doesn't have a non-`const` pointer. If you want to protect against that, then you'd need to copy the data instead of just using the pointer.

Comment: This is only delaying the problem. As I said, the actual data is not known at compile time. I can't create the constructor paramater at runtime.

Comment: Yes you can. Why wouldn't you be able to? Can you edit your question to show the code you tried to do that that didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

```
Mesh::Mesh(const float *vertices): m_vertices(vertices)
{
}

float number = 3.141;  // e.g.
int size = 10;
const float *vertices = &number;  // e.g.

vertices_ptr = new float[ size ];


meshPtr = new Mesh( vertices_ptr);
```

access it by `meshPtr->  ...`

Comment: Might not need `new` here. Set up the scope correctly and `std::vector` will do the job.